# copy paste was working on its own

Tags: copy-and-paste

I have Ubuntu Laptop ( from System76) . Am facing issues when I type a text/line be it either in email/notepad/document. Say that am typing a doc of 10 lines when I am typing 2nd line my cursor suddenly jumps to line 1 (or any place)and pasting the text which i previously copied or a different content even from my social media chats , if am typing in 5th line then all of sudden it jumps to line 2 or 3 and pasting some content. It is annoying me a lot even for a simple document/email I am forced to spend more time to correct the issues caused by this.

Please help me to resolve this, thanks.

Note: "Ubuntu 18.04.3 LTS" - this is the version I have.

Comment: Do you by any chance accidentally keep touching the touchpad while typing and also simulate the mouse middle-click (e.g. three finger tap or tapping a specific area of the touchpad that causes middle-click)?

Comment: No, i am not touching the touchpad .